# What is a name for a circle that has half of itself in one plane and half in another?

Tags: circles

What is a name for a circle that has half of itself in one plane and half in another?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no name for this. You're welcome to call it a "split circle" or something if you need a name for it.